# Import JSON Data to table with schema

Tags: sql, json, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I store JSON objects in a column (string).  I want to convert it to a table with schema.

| JSON_DATA |
| --- |
| {"id":"ksah2132","connections":{"structure":["123","456","789"]},"options":[{"id":"AA123","type":"optionA"},{"id":"BB123","type":"optionB"},{"id":"CC123","type":"optionC"}]} |
| {"id":"ksah3321","connections":{"structure":["567","332","435"]},"options":[{"id":"AA133","type":"optionA"},{"id":"BB156","type":"optionB"},{"id":"CC445","type":"optionC"}]} |

Table with Schema:

```
CREATE TABLE `sandboxabc.raw_data`(`options` array<struct<id:string,type:string>>, `connections` struct<structure:array<string>>, `id` string)
```

How can I use Spark SQL to insert overwrite into the new table?
My code:

```
INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE sandboxabc.structured_data
SELECT
    from_json (JSON_DATA,'$.options') AS options
    ,from_json (JSON_DATA,'$.connections') AS connections
    ,from_json (JSON_DATA,'$.id') AS id
FROM
    sandboxabc.raw_data
```

Sample of output:

| id | connection | option |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ksah2132 | {"structure":["123","456","789"]} | [{"id":"AA123","type":"optionA"},{"id":"BB123","type":"optionB"},{"id":"CC123","type":"optionC"} |

Comment: 1. The JSON_DATA String is not correct it requires one more opening and closing curly braces { } (one in the start and one in the end)

Comment: 2. Do you have data in Raw table like you have shown in the create statement, and you want to read raw table and transfer it in structured format in "sttuctured_data" ? Then can you post the sample output of structured_data you need?

Comment: @Pradeepyadav Yes, sample is provided..

Answer (score 0):

Below spark-sql code should work for you. Please note that hive support should be enabled and hive related jars should be present in classpath.

```
INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE sandboxabc.structured_data
  SELECT
    id,
    from_json(connection, "struct<structure:array<string>>") as connection,
    from_json(options, "array<struct<id:string,type:string>>") as options
      FROM (
        select
           get_json_object(JSON_DATA,'$.id') as id,
           get_json_object(JSON_DATA,'$.connection') as connection,
           get_json_object(JSON_DATA,'$.options') as options
      FROM sandboxabc.raw_data)
```